Ubuntu 24.04 I changed /bin/sh link to point to bash instead of dash now some things do not work
I ran a python program from PHP with Exec and it worked fine on Ubuntu 22.04 and Python 3.10.
I installed it on a development system with Ubuntu 24.04 and PHP 8.3.6 and Python 3.12 the PHP command exec('source /home/user/.venv/bin/activate  && python /home/user/pgm.py') produced the error 'dash source: not found'
I got the same result at the command line.  Some Google searches told me that "source" is a bash command that dash doesn't know about.
So I changed the link /bin/sh to point to /bin/bash and rebooted.  However, connecting to remote mysql now times out.
I stopped the ufw service, but that made no difference.  So I changed the /bin/sh back to dash and rebooted but still couldn't connect to mysql. In the end, I fixed this by reinstalling mysql, but
I still can't get the PHP command to run the python.
More info:
# ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Sep 18 12:42 /bin/sh -> dash

# readlink -f /bin/sh
/usr/bin/dash

This is the php code that tries to run the python script:
exec('. /home/user/.venv/bin/activate && python /home/user/pgm.py')

Here is the actual code snippet from inside a while loop the loops through the record set and sets the variables.
$cmd=(". /home/jerry/torch/.venv/bin/activate && python /home/jerry/torch/trans-rec.py  $filespec  $transdir"); 
$x=array(); 
exec($cmd, $x); 
$jx=json_encode($x); 
logit("Command='$cmd'\n\tResult: $jx");
unset($x);

The logit() function is outside the loop:
function logit($msg) {
    $fdate=date("Y-m-d");
    $f=fopen("/var/spool/asterisk/transcribe_$fdate.log","a");
    $text=date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "  $msg\n";
    $x=fwrite($f,$text);
    fclose($f);
    echo $text;
}

The output is always
2024-09-19 12:25:12  Command='source /home/jerry/torch/.venv/bin/activate && python
 /home/jerry/torch/trans-rec.py 
 /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/2024/09/19/in-18009654290-2489960108-20240919-120603-1726761963.4016.wav
 /var/spool/asterisk/transcriptions'
 Result: []

Note that Result should contain all the python output and the command does not contain "source" but "." -- PHP must be expanding it.
One more thing: My root login uses bash, and the command
# source /home/jerry/torch/.venv/bin/activate && python /home/jerry/torch/trans-rec.py /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/2024/09/19/external-6201-4019996009-20240919-104039-1726756840.3946.wav
 /var/spool/asterisk/

Works  fine from the command line.

Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you [edit] your question to have the correct names and versions of the tools you're using? PHP 10 does not exist, and PHP 3.x was deprecated back in the spring of 2000 when PHP 4.0.0 was released.

For next time, just use exec('. /home/user/.venv/bin/activate && python /home/user/pgm.py'). The command . is standard, bash only provides source as a synonym to the standard, portable . command.

I fixed version numbers. @terdon: does . work in place of source in dash?

Yes, it works in dash and all other POSIX-compliant shells. source is the odd one.

For your main issue, can you please add the output of ls -l /bin/sh and readlink -f /bin/sh`? Also show us how you connect to myslq and what happens when you try (any errors?).

I updated the post

How can I accept @terdon's comment as an answer?

You can't, comments can't be accepted, but it wasn't an answer anyway, just a step along the way. Now, are you 100% sure that you have . in the PHP code and PHP itself decides to change it to source? That seems extremely weird, surely not even PHP would do that. Can you double check? It is your logit("Command='$cmd'\n\tResult: $jx"); command that prints out the command, so are you saying that logit is changing its input? Finally, try changing your command to: $cmd=("bash -c '. /home/jerry/torch/.venv/bin/activate && python ...'), to call bash explicitly. Does that work?

If $filespec and $transdir are user-controlled, you should absolutely sanitize them, cause even using quotes as in terdon's answer those are super-injectable at the PHP level. Try setting $filespec to an empty string and $transdir to something like "; ls -la; echo ".

The default /bin/sh of Ubuntu is dash, not bash. Dash is a simple POSIX shell, which is faster but has fewer features than bash which has various extensions to the POSIX standard. When making a system call from a programming language using exec or system or the various equivalents in the various scripting languages, that is run using /bin/sh. However, python $venv/bin/activate scripts need to be run with bash or zsh:

This is also mentioned in the activate script:
$ python -m venv foo
$ head -n2  foo/bin/activate
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# You cannot run it directly

Which means that my initial advice to you in the comments, to use the portable, standard . instead of the bashsism source, was wrong. You don't want portability here, so using source is better since you must use bash or zsh.
So, since the /bin/sh is actually dash, you can't just run this command with exec(), as that will try to source the activate script in dash which will fail. What you therefore need to do, is to explicitly call it with bash. So change your code to:
## I don't really know PHP, do you really need the parentheses here?
$cmd=("/bin/bash -c '. /home/jerry/torch/.venv/bin/activate && python /home/jerry/torch/trans-rec.py  \"$filespec\" \"$transdir\"'"); 
$x=array(); 
exec($cmd, $x); 
$jx=json_encode($x); 
logit("Command='$cmd'\n\tResult: $jx");
unset($x);

Note how I also quoted the $filespec and $transdir variables when passing them to the shell. NEVER pass unquoted variables to shells.

As explained under OP's question quoting unfortunately doesn't prevent injection at the PHP level, if those variables are user-controlled they should still undergo sanitization (security is clearly beyond the scope of the question, but I felt like pointing this out)

@kos of course you should sanitize, but if you don't quote, you can't even pass variables with spaces. And if you have injection at the PHP level, that's a whole different level of problem.

Absolutely you should quote, and you rightfully pointed that out in your answer; I didn't at any rate mean the issue with OP's PHP code should be addressed in the answer, my comment was just for clarity / completeness since you linked to an article discussing the security implications of not quoting; it might not be obvious to everyone that there's a perhaps even more glaring issue (at the PHP level) with running OP's code as is on unsanitized user input.

@kos I was under the impression that using PHP is a security issue already :P

Ah yes no doubt the ship will sink while they're trying to fill that hole anywas :D
